# What is the syntax of using if-condition in a Karate test step?

Tags: karate

What is the syntax of using if-condition in Karate test step?

From the examples on the Karate GitHub documentation, I have inferred that this should work:

```
Background:
  * if (env == 'dev') configure ssl = false
  ...
```

But, it results in an error like this:

```
debug server listening on port: 4711
*** step failed: -unknown-:13 - javascript evaluation failed: if (env == 'dev') 
  configure ssl = false, <eval>:1:28 Expected ; but found ssl
if (env == 'dev') configure ssl = true
                            ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 28
```

I know how I can work around this and configure this particular item on the Karate config, but since I would like to use the if-condition on other various steps, I am just wondering how to use it as a tool to do it as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional logic are actually javascript functions so instead of using DSL you could use [karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object).

try,

`* if (env == 'dev') karate.configure("ssl", true)`

Comment: this is correct. note the subtle difference between the JS API and the DSL syntax, refer https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure (see last line)